# Apache problem while I restart it

Tags: apache2

When I try to restart the apache I get an error massage :

- Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]
- The apache2 configtest failed.

Output of config test was:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zzz-deny-generic.conf:
Invalid ServerName "*" use ServerAlias to set multiple server names.
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I can't find any other Google results for "zzz-deny-generic".  Is this a file you've installed yourself?  What does it contain? The problem is in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Probably at line 20 of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zzz-deny-generic.conf` is present something like:

```
 ServerName *
```

According to [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername), ServerName syntax is:

```
 ServerName [scheme://]fully-qualified-domain-name[:port]
```

As I can understand this last configuration file would deny any request that is not matched by previous `VirtualHost`.

Depending on your specific situation you could remove `ServerName` directive.